# Shiny R leaflet AddMarkers NULL value error

Tags: r, csv, shiny, leaflet

I am trying to create a leaflet Shiny app however I keep getting the `Warning: Error in derivePoints: addMarkers requires non-NULL longitude/latitude values` Error. I have attached the code herewith. Also, a screenshot of the input data files and links to download.

DataBooks.csv

[image]

GPSBook.csv

[image]

Code:

```
    library(shiny)
    library(leaflet)

    Location_levels=list(Institutional=0, Provincial=1, National=2, International=3)
    DataBook <- read.csv("~/R_Projects/TNL_Network/DataBook.csv", comment.char="#")
    GPSBook <- read.csv("~/R_Projects/TNL_Network/GPSBook.csv", comment.char="#")

    ## Create content for the popups in the markers
    popUpContent <- function(ins_id){
      subs<-subset(DataBook, Institute_id==ins_id)
      name <- subs$Institute[[1]]
      return(name[[1]])
    }
    
    ## Get unique markers based on the location type selected. This function calls the popup content function above and returns a dataframe
    markerData <- function(location){
      subs1<-subset(DataBook, Location_level<=Location_levels[location])
      unique_ins_ids<-levels(factor(subs1$Institute_id))
      mdata.list <- vector("list", length(unique_ins_ids))
      for(i in 1:length(unique_ins_ids)){
        mdata.list[[i]] <- list(subset(GPSBook, Institute_id==unique_ins_ids[i])["Longitude"][[1]], subset(GPSBook, Institute_id==unique_ins_ids[i])["Latitude"][[1]],
                        as.character(popUpContent(unique_ins_ids[i])))
      }
      solution <- do.call('rbind', mdata.list)
      dataf<-data.frame(solution)
      colnames(dataf)<-c("lat", "long", "Msg") ## I ihave mixed up the origincal longitude and latitude. I invert it here. 
      return(dataf)
    }
    
    ## Function to create initial data. 
    initData <- function(){
      return(markerData("International"))
    }
    init_dataset <- initData()

    ui <- fluidPage(
      leafletOutput("mymap"),
      p(),
      radioButtons(inputId = "radio", label = "", choices = as.list(levels(DataBook$Location)), selected = "International")
    )

    server <- function(input, output, session) {
      observe({
        proxy <- leafletProxy("mymap", data = markerData(input$radio))
        proxy %>% clearMarkers()
        proxy %>% addMarkers()
      })

      output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
        leaflet(data = markerData(input$radio)) %>% addTiles() %>%
          addMarkers()
      })
    }

    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thanks a lot for the help.
Links to files.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-TWCTRv7UM1bnVpWEIxTnB2d28

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-TWCTRv7UM1cjBxNnlhR2ZXc0U

Comment: Can you provide the csv files? Or some sample from the files to test the code?

Comment: Edited the question to include the data files. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I have understood you intention. If yes this can be simplified a lot.
This is how I would do it. (just change back to the correct directories where your csv files are). The code:

```
    library(shiny)
    library(leaflet)


    DataBook <- read.csv("./data/DataBook.csv", comment.char="#")
    GPSBook <- read.csv("./data/GPSBook.csv", comment.char="#")
    names(GPSBook) <- names(GPSBook)[c(1,2,4,3)]

    ui <- fluidPage(
            leafletOutput("mymap"),
            p(),
            radioButtons(inputId = "radio", label = "", choices = as.list(levels(DataBook$Location)), selected = "International")
    )

    server <- function(input, output, session) {

            location <- reactive({
                    tmp <- subset(DataBook, Location_level <= Location_levels[input$radio])
                    uniqueIds <- unique(tmp$Institute_id)
                    tmpGps <- subset(GPSBook, Institute_id %in% uniqueIds)


            })

            observe({
                    proxy <- leafletProxy("mymap", data = location())
                    proxy %>% clearMarkers()
                    proxy %>% addMarkers(popup = ~as.character(Name))
            })

            output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
                    leaflet(data = GPSBook) %>% addTiles() %>%
                            addMarkers(popup = ~as.character(Name))
            })
    }

    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

In your original code the function was creating a list so the data was not prepared as leaflet would expect them to be.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the help. The code works great. One question, how can reset the view to only show the markers visible. So, if I select provincial, I want the map to zoom in only. Thanks again.

Comment: Try adding this in the leaflet proxy part: proxy %>% setView(lng = mean(location()$Longitude), lat = mean(location()$Latitude), zoom = 4)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I also did it using this code. `fitBounds(lng1 = max(location()$Longitude),lat1 = max(location()$Latitude),
                        lng2 = min(location()$Longitude),lat2 = min(location()$Latitude))`

Comment: Glad I could help!